# Lightbox open bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am facing a problem in opening lightbox in bootstrap carousel what I mean I just put my lightbox box as item in carousel item.but when click on lightbox its not taking width and height of view port it is only taking the carousel width and height.after debugging I came to know.its happening because of transform property on active element
transform: translate3d(0,0,0) and perspective property.
What should I do to remove this property on child either by jquery or css

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you show your code achievements

Comment: How would I post with folder (less,CSS,js)